# Improve accuracy after using one-hot encoding, if number of features increases

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm solving the Telstra Network Disruptions problem originally by combining all data files. I got 480+ columns and after that I've done one-hot encoding and my columns become approximately 1568. Now accuracy is not good. What to do to reduce columns and improve accuracy? I already applied PCA.

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't enough information in the question; I'll take a dig with whats available. 
With so many columns; the data becomes sparse. Try to use L1 regularization in your classifier